# Data loaded in Angular shows as String instead of Object when getting it from Header var

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-apicontroller

On an Angular Controller I have the following function:

```
vm.test = function () {
  testService.test()
    .then(function (response) {
      var pagination = response.data;
      var xPagination = response.headers("x-pagination");
      console.log(pagination);
      console.log(xPagination);
    })
}
```

On the console I see that for pagination is an Object but xPagination shows as:

```
 { "pageNumber": 2}
```

So I get undefined when I try:

```
 console.log(xPagination.pageNumber);
```

But I do not have that problem when using pagination.pageNumber.

The test API I am calling uses ASP.NET API and I have:

On ASP.NET Web Api I have the following:

```
// This is test code to isolate the problem
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test() {

  Pagination pagination = new Pagination { PageNumber = 2 }; 

  HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<Pagination>(HttpStatusCode.OK, pagination);

  String xPagination = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pagination, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });

  response.Headers.Add("x-pagination", xPagination);

  return ResponseMessage(response);

}
```

What am I missing? I would like xPagination to be an Object in Angular.

Am I doing something wrong in the API or do I need to do something else on Angular part?

Comment: Headers SHOULD be strings, but in your case xPagination could be a JSON string. Have you tried `JSON.parse(xPagination)`?

Comment: Now I tried ... Using JSON.parse or angular.fromJson works fine ... I just wasn't sure if I should do something else on my api.

Comment: No, it's working correctly. The fact that you had to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` should be an indicator that it needs to be de-serialized on the other end.
Also I wouldn't recommend using headers to send that kind of data (not sure why you'd need to anyway, when you've already got what you need in response.data).
Webservers put a size limit on headers, so you might run into issues if your data becomes too big. If you're wanting to send multiple types of data, create a new class that includes pagination data and other kinds of data explicitly and return that.